# How can I install pygame 1.9.2 on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: package-management, python, ppa, python-2.7

The `python-pygame` package contains version 1.9.1release, but I need features from 1.9.2.  Is there a PPA available for the latest pygame release?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, so I recommend just downloading the source for now and wait for this version to hit the repos. It wouldn't really make sense to create a PPA for this, since it will be in the actual repos in just a couple of months.

Download the source here [at its new bitbucket home](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/wiki/Home). Some instructions are also available on the wiki for compiling and installing pygame.

Comment: Still isn't as of Nov 2015.